# Does Symfony 2.0 Support Propel?

Tags: orm, symfony

Soon Symfony 2.0 will release and i have visited its website i.e www.symfony.com, but in Documentation and ebooks its only giving Doctrine as ORM. Have they stopped supporting Propel?
Because i am using Symfony1.4 with Propel as ORM, and i am comfortable with Propel. Do i have to migrate to Doctrine, or just they will bring on Propel after stable release.

Comment: Nice work @William, any help or idea on this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367077/symfony2s-propelbundle-database-reverse-enginering-issue>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Propel bundle available: http://symfony2bundles.org/willdurand/PropelBundle But I don't know how stable it is.

Comment: gehrig in Symfony 1.3, 1.4 the default ORM was Doctrine, and we have to select the ORM as Propel during the creation of Project. do have to do like that in 2.0

Comment: I think they support Propel in Symfony 2 via this separate bundle so you should be able to continue with Propel.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the creator of this bundle. It works fine and it's up to date :)