# Symfony2: How to make a pgsql database reverse enginering process with PropelBundle?

Tags: symfony, propel

I've successfully integrated Symfony2 with [PropelBundle](http://symfony2bundles.org/willdurand/PropelBundle) but I'm having troubles to realize a reverse engineering process with a pgsql driver over a database deployed in a posgresql-8.4 server. In order to do that I ran a `php app/console propel:reverse` command to generate the XML schema and I obtained the following error:

```
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata:
  SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7
  ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"
```

Any ideas? My station is an Ubuntu 10.10 and the full process's console log was:

```
Use connection named default
Buildfile: /var/www/symfony2/vendor/propel/generator/build.xml
[resolvepath] Resolved /tmp/propel-gen to /tmp/propel-gen

propel-project-builder > check-project-or-dir-set:
propel-project-builder > check-project-set:
propel-project-builder > set-project-dir:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-exists:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops-for-propel-gen:
propel-project-builder > check-buildprops:
propel-project-builder > configure:

     [echo] Loading project-specific props from /tmp/propel-gen/build.properties
 [property] Loading /tmp/propel-gen/build.properties

propel-project-builder > reverse:

    [phing] Calling Buildfile '/var/www/symfony2/vendor/propel/generator/build-propel.xml' with target 'reverse'
 [property] Loading /var/www/symfony2/vendor/propel/generator/./default.properties

propel > reverse:

     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] | Generating XML from PDO connection !          |
     [echo] |                                               |
     [echo] +-----------------------------------------------+

[propel-schema-reverse] Reading database structure...
[propel-schema-reverse] There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[42704]: Undefined object: 7 ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "tables"

BUILD FINISHED

Total time: 1.6386 second

[ErrorException]

  Warning: copy(/tmp/propel-gen/schema.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/symfony2/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Util/Filesystem.php line 44  

propel:reverse [--connection[="..."]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just saw your question.

I recommend you to update both Propel and PropelBundle to last versions on the Propel ORM organization: http://github.com/propelorm.

Comment: just now I saw this answer, It's been a while and I solved the problem  I don't remember how, but thanks for answer.